# Microsoft.SqlServer.Server namespace

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I'm trying to implement a Common Language Runtime (CLR) assembly to use with SQL Server. For creating dll I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

I have the following code from an example tutorial:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;


namespace Split
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [SqlFunction(
            DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None,
            FillRowMethodName = "MyFillRowMethod"
            , IsDeterministic = true)
        ]

        public static IEnumerable Split(string stringToSplit, string delimiters)
        {

            string[] elements = stringToSplit.Split(delimiters.ToCharArray());
            return elements;
        }

        public static void MyFillRowMethod(Object theItem, out SqlChars results)
        {
            results = new SqlChars(theItem.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

But I encounter this error:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'SqlServer' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Can anybody show me the way of fixing my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**As the error message hinted at:**

You're probably missing the reference to `System.Data.SqlClient`, which contains the `SqlFunctionAttribute` in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server` namespace.

1. Right click on your project and click on `Manage NuGet Packages...`

   [image: NuGet]
2. Search for `System.Data.SqlClient`

   [image]
3. Install

   [image]

That should resolve your issue.

Comment: Why would someone have to get a NuGet package for something that is part of the .NET  Framework itself. From Microsoft: *"CLR integration functionality is exposed in an assembly called System.Data.dll, which is part of the .NET Framework. This assembly can be found in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) as well as in the .NET Framework directory. A reference to this assembly is typically added automatically by both command line tools and Microsoft Visual Studio, so there's no need to add it manually."*

Comment: Because I assumed that the author wasn't talking about the .NET framework version but instead about .NET Core, where the SqlClient has been moved out into a separate package.